# Is it possible to add another `Open With` item to the Explorer's context menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I added a file type using the `ftype` command. Now I want to add another `ftype` for use with the `Open With` context menu.

Is this possible?  If so, how?  If not, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a filetype opens in default in Microsoft Notepad for example, I rightclick and choose `Open With...`

From there I browse, choose my program once I find it, and then once I do that one time it appears the next tme I right click and choose `Open With...`

So you do have to manually do find the program the first time per filetype, but after that it should appear automatically under `Open With...`

Comment: Doesn't work for calling programmes using a specific command line layout.  I.e. a command that doesn't accept the file name as the last command line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor and copy the contents below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Notepad]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Notepad\command]
@="notepad.exe %1"
```

Change the contents as necessary and save as a .reg file.

Double click the .reg file and accept any UAC prompts. The new entry will now be in the context menu.

Comment: So you're saying it's NOT possible with `ftype`.

Comment: dont know.  just giving you another way.

Comment: @Keltari: Don't use blockquote or >, use pre or code instead (indent by 4 spaces). The former messes with backslashes as you can see in your original answer. Especially important with something like a .REG file. You don't want to be held responsible for messing someone's registry!

Comment: @Adrian: No, what you want isn't possible to achieve using `ftype`. Also note that Keltari's .REG file above will add the Open with Notepad command to *all* file types. If you want to add for only, say .TXT, you need to navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt`, find out the ProgID i.e. **txtfile**, then go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell`.